# Difference between Java stream().noneMatch(...) and !stream().anyMatch(...)

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is there is any difference in performance or anything else if I do

1. `list.stream().noneMatch(...)`
2. `!list.stream().anyMatch(...)`

Comment: It depends on the likelihood and most notable on the different `...`s in your code.

Comment: @U.Windl since the OP obviously means the same `...` for both, it does not.

Comment: @Holger: noneMatch() most likely ends after having examined all the elements, while anyMatch() can end after having found the first match.

Comment: @U.Windl read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57779846/2711488). Both stop at the first match. The only difference is the opposite boolean result.

Comment: @Holger: If both constructs shall be equivalent the `...`s must be different.

Comment: @U.Windl there is a `!` (logical not) before the second construct. Assuming identical `...`, they *are* equivalent.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both [`noneMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#noneMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)) and [`anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)) are short-circuiting stream operations.  That means that they will stop processing their input when the result becomes known.

In your case, they will each stop when they do find a match to the Predicate that is passed in.  The only difference is that `noneMatch` will return `false` on a match and `anyMatch` will return `true`.  Your negating the result from `anyMatch` makes the two expressions logically equivalent.

Assuming the same `list` and the same `Predicate`, any performance difference would be negligible.  Both methods will short-circuit on the first match, if any, working through the entire list if none actually match, and one negation operator won't make a difference either.

Comment: …and those who are still not convinced, may try `System.out.println(IntStream.range(0,1_000).peek(System.out::println).noneMatch(i-> i==5)); 
 System.out.println(IntStream.range(0,1_000).peek(System.out::println).anyMatch(i-> i==5));`…